# Vibrating Beam equation with a pulsating force

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Consider the following equation $$u_{tt}+a^2u_{xxxx}=f(t),$$ for $-L<x<L$ and $t>0$, with boundary conditions $u(\pm L,t)=0=u_{x}(\pm L,t)$ and $u(x,0)=0=u_{t}(x,0)$. Im asked to prove that the eigenfunctions corresponding to different eigenvalues λ are
mutually orthogonal, that the eigenvalues λ of the boundary-value problem are all either
strictly positive or strictly negative and to obtain the solution as a series of eigenfunctions.

Firts I tried to solve the homogeneus case with separation of variables, and I ended up with the equations $$T''+a^2\lambda T=0,$$ and $$X^{iv}-\lambda X=0, X(\pm L)=0=X'(\pm L).$$ About the sign of the eigenvalues i ended up with them being strictly positive, i don't know if i made a mistake but with energy methods we can prove that $$\lambda \int_{-L}^L |X|^2dx=\int_{-L}^L X^{iv}\overline{X}dx=-\int_{-L}^L X'''\overline{X'}dx=\int_{-L}^L X''\overline{X''}dx=\int_{-L}^L|X''|^2dx.$$ So $\lambda\geq 0$, and $\lambda=0$ leds up to the trivial solution. Now the solution to the problem is $$X(x)=A\cosh (\mu x)+B\sinh (\mu x)+C\cos (\mu x)+D\sin (\mu x),$$ where $\lambda=\mu^4$ for some $\mu>0$. Imposing the boundary conditions we end with the trascendetal equation for the eigenvalues $$\tanh (\mu L)=\tan (\mu L),$$ so there are a family of strictly increasing eigenvalues $\mu_1<\mu_2<\cdots$, and the family of eigenfunctions $$X_n(x)=A_n\cosh (\mu_n x)+B_n\sinh (\mu_n x)+C_n\cos (\mu_n x)+D_n\sin (\mu_n x).$$ Now im stuck trying to prove that these eigenfunctions are orthogonal, and also how to proceed in the non homogeneus case, in particular i want $f(t)=C \sin (\omega t).$ Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof that eigenfunctions corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal is similar to your proof that the eigenvalues are strictly positive. Let $X_m$ and $X_n$ be the eigenfunctions corresponding to $\lambda_m$ and $\lambda_n$, respectively, with $\lambda_m\neq\lambda_n$. Then
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\lambda_m\int_{-L}^LX_mX_n\,dx&=\int_{-L}^LX_m^{(4)}X_n\,dx \\
&=\cancelto{0}{\left.X_m'''X_n\right|_{-L}^L}-\int_{-L}^LX_m'''X_n'\,dx \\
&=-\cancelto{0}{\left.X_m''X_n'\right|_{-L}^L}+\int_{-L}^LX_m''X_n''\,dx \\
&=\cancelto{0}{\left.X_m'X_n''\right|_{-L}^L}-\int_{-L}^LX_m'X_n'''\,dx \\
&=-\cancelto{0}{\left.X_mX_n'''\right|_{-L}^L}+\int_{-L}^LX_mX_n^{(4)}\,dx \\
&=\lambda_n\int_{-L}^LX_mX_n\,dx. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Since $\lambda_m\neq\lambda_n$, it follows from $(1)$ that $\int_{-L}^LX_mX_n\,dx=0.$

---

Now let's find the solution to $u_{tt}+a^2u_{xxxx}=f(t)$ expressed as a series of eigenfunctions. For this, we write the solution as
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_n(t)X_n(x), \tag{2}
$$
where we assume the eigenfunctions $X_n$ are normalized to $1$, i.e.,
$\int_{-L}^LX_n^2\,dx = 1.$ Plugging $(2)$ into the PDE, we obtain
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[T_n''(t)+a^2\lambda_nT_n(t)]X_n(x)=f(t). \tag{3}
$$
Multiplying both sides of $(3)$ by $X_m$, and using the orthogonality relation $\int_{-L}^LX_mX_n\,dx=\delta_{mn}$, we obtain the family of ODEs
$$
T_m''(t)+a^2\lambda_mT_m(t)=C_mf(t)\qquad(m\in\mathbb{N}^{*}), \tag{4}
$$
where $C_m=\int_{-L}^L X_m\,dx.$ In order to satisfy the initial condition $u(x,0)=0=u_t(x,0)$, we must solve $(4)$ with the initial condition $T_m(0)=0=T_m'(0)$. The result is
$$
T_m(t)=\frac{C_m}{\omega_m}\int_0^t\sin(\omega_m(t-s))f(s)\,ds
\qquad\left(\omega_m=\sqrt{a^2\lambda_m}\right). \tag{5}
$$
Eqs. $(2)$ and $(5)$ give the desired solution.

---

Finally, for completeness, I'll present the explicit expression of the eigenfunctions $X_n(x)$. Since the differential operator $\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}$ and the boundary conditions $X(\pm L)=0=X'(\pm L)$ commute with the parity operator $\mathcal{P}:x\mapsto -x$, we can find a basis of eigenfunctions that have definite parity, i.e., are even or odd functions of $x$. The even eigenfunctions have the form
$$
X_{\text{even}}(x)=A_{\mu}[\cosh(\mu L)\cos(\mu x)-\cos(\mu L)\cosh(\mu x)]. \tag{6}
$$
It's trivial to verify that $X_{\text{even}}(\pm L)=0$; however, in order that
$X_{\text{even}}'(\pm L)=0$, $\mu$ must satisfy the condition
$$
-\cosh(\mu L)\sin(\pm\mu L)-\cos(\mu L)\sinh(\pm\mu L)=0
\implies \tan(\mu L)=-\tanh(\mu L). \tag{7}
$$
Similarly, the odd eigenfunctions have the form
$$
X_{\text{odd}}(x)=B_{\mu}[\sinh(\mu L)\sin(\mu x)-\sin(\mu L)\sinh(\mu x)], \tag{8}
$$
with $\mu$ fixed by the boundary condition $X_{\text{odd}}'(\pm L)=0$:
$$
\sinh(\mu L)\cos(\pm\mu x)-\sin(\mu L)\cosh(\pm\mu x)=0
\implies \tan(\mu L)=\tanh(\mu L). \tag{9}
$$
Notice that the series $(2)$ contains only even eigenfunctions, as $C_n=\int_{-L}^LX_n(x)\,dx=0$ if $X_n$ is an odd function of $x$.